# How does Cross Site scriptng work between texts?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I injected Stored XSS into text field in Webgoat5.4-developer[XSS-LAB : Cross Site Scripting - Stage1 : Stored XSS]. The XSS I injected was

```
2211 <script>alert('Hi')</script>HyperThread Rd.
```

where 2211 and HyperThread are just already exsited text which and

```
<script>alert('Hi Jerry u r hacked lol')</script>
```

is script command I injected. And then, it works. But the question is I'm wondering how it works even though script command was between texts.

Comment: That is the whole point of XSS. Input might not necessarily be encoded correctly and HTML elements might thus be interpreted by the browser. The `<script>` element might contain JavaScript code that might be executed. That is exactly why you always have to ensure that input is properly encoded.